# Petunia flowers, edible or not?

Tags: edible

If I grow petunias from a seed are the flowers safe to be used as food decoration. Can they safely be eaten?

Answer (score 2):

According to [poison.org](https://www.poison.org/articles/plant) and [the University of California](https://ucanr.edu/sites/poisonous_safe_plants/Safe_Plants_by_Common_Name/) they're non-poisonous. This does not mean that they're a tasty edible, however. Personally, I'd use nasturtiums instead of petunias - those flowers are IMO prettier and they're definitely edible. If you're making your food decoration in mid-summer and want a trumpet-shaped flower, then use a small-flowered daylily like the ubiquitous Stella d'Oro. Daylily flowers are also edible.

Comment: I´m very grateful of Your answer! And thank you for the extra information. I use nasturtiums already. Have a nice day!